# How to create ActiveX object in asp.net

Tags: javascript

How can i create ActiveX Object in java script using asp.net.what i need requirements to create that ActiveX object if i use any DLL to create that object and how can i create can anyone provide description of to create ActiveX object

My Tried code is:

```
 <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function getSize()

        {

            var oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

            var d = document.getElementById('b').value;

            var e = oas.getFile(d);

            var f = e.size;

            return(f);
        }

        function checkFileType()
        {

            var path = document.getElementById('file1').value;
            var Index = path.lastIndexOf(".");

            var length = path.length;
            var filetype = path.substring(Index,length)

            if ((filetype == ".doc") ||(filetype == ".pdf") ||(filetype == ".jpg") ||(filetype == ".gif") ||(filetype == ".xls")||(filetype==".odt"))
            {

                var x = getSize(); if (x > 5242880)
                {

                    alert('only upto 5 MB file is allowed');

                    return false;
                }

            }

            else

            {

                alert('Only .doc, .pdf, .jpg, .gif, .xls is allowed');return false;
            }



        }


</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="file" name="b" id="file1" onchange="return checkFileType();" />
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
```

In the above code i am getting this line in code
`" var oas = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");"` getting Exception is `"0x800a01ad - JavaScript runtime error: Automation server can't create object"`.
Can anyone tell me to how can i create ActiveX object properly and what i need setting and which DLL's i use and all can anyone help me out.

Thank You

Comment: That's client side code. It has nothing to do with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

This validation is not a supported method in all the browsers.

Anyway, for IE9 or below (where `.files` is not supported) you can use this. To use this method, you will need to enable activex object in IE.

Go to Internet Options->Security Tab. Select trusted website, and click Sites button. It will give you an option to add the url. Add the url of your site, and save. Then click on the button saying "custom levels". It will open a list of options. Find the one saying "Initialize and script activex controls not marked as safe" and enable it.

Save and close the dialog boxes, and refresh your webpage.

Edit:

Few notes:

This is extremely unsecure method, so I would suggest improving compatibility and saying no to anything below IE9.

Secondly, this is something you have to enable on every single user's machine. Otherwise, that line will always throw an exception.

So, if you have to stick to IE8 or lower, and have control over your userbase, then only use this. Otherwise, just use flash upload method for IE browsers. Your users might hate installing flash, but there is nothing you can do.

P.S. I was doing this same thing about an hour ago. Lucky for you, I did all the research. :)

Edit: On a secondary note, can someone help me figure out how to get rid of XML dataislands without major rewrite? That is the only thing stopping me from saying goodbye to IE6.

Comment: I want to enable it "Initialize and script activex controls not marked as safe" it shows a warning message like your system might be at risk. what i do Ignore that  and that and make enable

Comment: Yes. Although, this means you are putting user's system at risk, if your website act silly. I am sure your servers are more secure than your user's system. :) Still, a risk is a risk. If you can help it, get rid of anything below ie9.

Comment: Thankyou for that. I am using IE 10. I changed all the mentioned above settings but i run it shows the again this exception   ' "0x800a01ad - JavaScript runtime error: Automation server can't create object" '. if i miss any code in .cs page and any dll can you tell me in detail.

Comment: can you please tell me to how can i do this?

Comment: I already did. Read the answer, mate. In every user's pc, go to internet setting. And then enable the option I mentioned. BTW, if you are using IE10 and you have no intention to support anything lower than IE9, then why are you using ActiveX again? HTML5's file input box provides a collection called files. You can get file properties that way, instead of doing this unsafe stuff.